# The inverse function of $f(x)=\ln(x)/x$.

Tags: functions, inverse-function

I don't know how to find the inverse function of the function $f(x) = \ln(x)/x$, and I'm not even sure it exists? Would appreciate any help.

EDIT: I've talked to my professor and he has told me that I should only consider the function on the domain $x > e$. With this constraint it should be possible to find an inverse function on the domain. But how?

Comment: It's not injective on the usual domain (i.e. positive values of x). So it can't be invertible on that domain.

Comment: $f(x)\to 0$ for $x\to \infty$. You might want be more specific.

Comment: @Dave please see my edit.

Answer (score 2):

Write it as $$ -\frac{\log(x)}{x} = -\log(x) e^{-\log(x)} = -y$$ to see the relation with [Lambert's $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function): $$-\log(x) = W(-y)$$ $$x = e^{-W(-y)}$$
Note that the $W$ function is multi-valued (to be expected by the remarks made in comments and other answers). For the domain $x\geq e$ you'll have to take the lower branch $W_{-1}$ on $[-1/e,0)$:
$$x = e^{-W_{-1}(-y)}$$

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: @Filofobo I did see your edit. See the last part of my answer.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand all the W business. Is there a simpler way to do it?

Comment: You can rewrite it as $-W_{-1}(-y)/y$ but the inverse will involve $W$ one way or other.